# grunt.log doesn't render Arabic strings correctly

Tags: node.js, utf-8, gruntjs, arabic, windows-console

How can I make nodejs display correctly Arabic characters? I m outputting an arabic string that I read from a file using gruntjs's log utility;

```
grunt.log.ok('مرحبا = hello');
```

But instead displays it like

[image: Nodejs command prompt]

After some further verification, I narrowed the problem origin and found that this is related to command prompt itself which does not support Arabic characters by default :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: The windows command prompt does not support UTF-8 out of the box, so you'll need to change the codepage for the terminal in order for it to display. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: tried `chcp 65001` and set font to Lucida console but still it didn't work.

Comment: You might need a different code page for arabic. or a different font. Or something?